# Remove invalid html characters while fetching CMS pages by id

Tags: cms, html, page-content

Using below code i'm getting cms page contents by page_id

```
$content = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load(6)->getContent();       

print_r($content);
```

it's fetching value from database, so i'm getting invalid special characters like /r/n added and all `</` is replaced with `<\/`

Is there any magento way to remove this invalid characters ?

Comment: hello feel free to accept amit's answer, if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Vinoth, $content is a `cms  content` for getting proper result you need to emulate this content using `Cms Emulator`,which give extract result of this container.

```
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($content);
```